# using union with join sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to sql and have been working on few queries.

I am trying to use union and join together.

It works otherwise if I dont output the number 0.

If someone can guide me on where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT m.movie_title, m.release_year,COUNT(c.actor_name) female_actors 
GROUP BY m.movie_title, m.release_year 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(c2.actor_name), 0
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? And see COALESCE

Comment: I am using sql (not sure which RDBMS that is) using oracle11g (if that helps). Looked at COALESCE and I am still a beginner. Want to stick to basics before I go ahead. Thank you though.

Comment: Why are you including irrelevant tags? -1

Comment: What is irrelevant about sql? just wondering

Comment: and just downvoting because someone doesnot understand the difference , It would be nice if you could help a person understand rather then just downvoting it.

Comment: Each tag comes with a user-contributed explanation

Comment: so rather then saying that, downvoting was easier I guess.

Comment: Yes. You've nailed it.

Comment: @Mani: I don't know why you've mutilated your query first posted. You were almost there, with only few flaws. UNION isn't necessary at all here and not even appropriate for the problem given. UNION (or better UNION ALL for that matter) adds another query result with the *same columns*. I suggest you read up on UNION to learn about its use and syntax.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you for explaining that. I did read up on it and it helped me clarify. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must outer join ACTOR, too. The inner join removes all outer joined CAST_MEMBER for there is of course no actor for the non-existent CAST_MEMBER. That's all there is to do.

```
SELECT m.movie_title, m.release_year, COUNT(c.actor_name) female_actors 
FROM MOVIE m 
LEFT JOIN CAST_MEMBER c on (m.movie_title = c.movie_title AND m.release_year = c.release_year) 
LEFT JOIN ACTOR a on (a.actor_name = c.actor_name AND a.gender = 'Female')
GROUP BY m.movie_title, m.release_year;
```

Comment: this query does work, but it doesnot achieve outputing a 0 for the records thats dont exist.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. I was in a hurry and made that COUNT(\*) which is wrong. You were right to count non-null fileds. I'm editing my answer accordingly. And of course `a.gender = 'Female'` belongs in the ON clause.

Comment: As a remark to the later reader: This is the originally posted query by Mani, with only the slight change to have ACTOR left-joined and the gender criteria moved to the ON clause, plus the unnecessary UNION part removed. Mani has meanwhile heavily changed the query in the request, so the query may look like my own invention. It isn't. It's Mani's. It only had minor flaws.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.movie_title, m.release_year,
       SUM(case when a.gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) female_actors 
FROM MOVIE m LEFT JOIN CAST_MEMBER c on(m.movie_title=c.movie_title AND m.release_year=c.release_year) JOIN ACTOR a on(a.actor_name=c.actor_name) 
GROUP BY m.movie_title, m.release_year
```

Comment: This query works only, if in CAST_MEMBER there is at least one entry per MOVIE (which is a reasonable assumption). So you can turn the LEFT JOIN on CAST_MEMBER into an INNER JOIN (which is what happens implicitly because of the INNER JOIN to ACTOR anyhow). If you also want to count for movies where no actors are yet entered, turn the INNER JOIN on ACTOR into a LEFT JOIN instead.